# dimmer on input of stepdown transformer for amp regulation?

Tags: voltage, transformer, microwave, step-down

If have a step-down transformer designed for low voltage high amps, and I put a dimmer on the input will that allow me to lower the output amps? I don't care about voltage as it will be negligible, I'm combining two coils in series 110v each stepped down from 100 coils to 2 coils. I'm anticipating over 300 amps, and I want to be able to easily adjust the amps.

Comment: Are you trying to build a welder? If so, your input dimmer should be able to deal with the full power available form the two transformers you intend to use, and keep also in mind that not all transformers are designed to work with the secondary winding short circuited for a long time.

Comment: You will need a dimmer rated for 1200 watts at 240 volts. That may be difficult to find, but if you can find it it will probably do what you want. This sounds like building a welder using microwave oven transformers. There are questions here an extensive instructions and discussions on various sites. You should probably study them. I am not sure you are really asking the right question.

Answer (score 0):

Two things. First, make sure your transformer secondary can handle the current. 300A needs large wire to handle the current, and an ample-sized core to prevent saturation.

Second, while a dimmer could work, a device called a variac (variable auto transformer) would work much better as it will give undistorted AC.